# NumberFormatException using <c:url in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el, numberformatexception

In my web app,I have an Item class with

```
public class Item {
    private Long item_id;
    private String name;
...
}

...
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>edititemservlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/edititem</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
...
```

While listing the items,I tried to use

```
<a href="<c:url value="editItem?itemId=${item.item_id}" />" >${item.name}</a>
```

This works .But, when I tried the following to use

```
<c:url value="editItem" var="editItemurl">
    <c:param name="itemId" value="${item.item_id}" />
</c:url>
<c:forEach var="item" items="${items}" varStatus="itemslistCount">
<tr><td>${itemslistCount.count} </td>
<td><a href="${editItemurl}" >${item.name}</a></td>
```

I expected to get the same result.
But this causes NumbeFformatException .

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:424)
```

I tried to print
${editItemurl}  and it displays an empty string.

Any idea how I can correct this?

thanks

mark

p.s:
here is the stack trace

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:424)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:461)
    at myshop.servlets.ItemEditServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the cause of the exception. Do you have some more stacktrace? Please also mention which JSTL version you're using. Regardless, you should actually be placing the `<c:url>` inside the `<c:forEach>` in order to have access to `${item}`.

Comment: @BalusC .sorry for the foolish mistake..I should have figured it out myself..thanks a million

Comment: Did it solve the problem? I'll repost the comment as an answer. I however still wonder why the NFE is been thrown. I wouldn't expect it to be thrown in this construct. Can you please include the entire stacktrace?

Answer (score 3):

The `<c:url>` has to go inside `<c:forEach>` in order to have access to `${item}`.

However, I can't explain why the NFE is been thrown. For that I would need to know the entire stacktrace.

Comment: sorry..was away for the night..I think it was because empty string was passed for item_id and that caused a NFE at Long.parseLong()..

Comment: I see that you included the stacktrace in the question. The stacktrace just indicate a bug in your own servlet code, not in the `<c:url>` implementation. This exception only occurs when you submit the form, not when you display the form. Your servlet is blindly expecting a number as request parameter without validating it first. So there is no problem at all in the `<c:url>` implementation.